# laravel model save() will save duplicated data in db

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I wrote some code learn from a php/laravel video tutorial . but the result is not the same.
the problem step is:

1. create a db table named questions and a model named Question.
2. add a function to save data into db.
3. in this function, use bellow code:

   ```
   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

   class Question extends Model
   {
       public function add_question(){
           $this->title = rq('title');
           $this->user_id = session('user_id');
           if(rq('description'))
               $this->desc = rq('description');
           $result = $this->save();
           //dump($result);
           return( $result)?
                ['status'=> '1' , 'id'=>$this->id] :
                ['status'=> '0' , 'message'=>'db save fail'];
       }
   }
   ```
4. run in browser 
   http://localhost/api/question/add?title=rrrrr&description=tttttt
   and check db, there will be two same records. like bellow:

   ```
   id  title   descdescription  user_id    status  created_at       updated_at
   12  rrrrr   tttttt           18         ok      2019/4/7 16:55   2019/4/7 16:55
   13  rrrrr   tttttt           18         ok      2019/4/7 16:55   2019/4/7 16:55
   ```

   it is not same result as it is in the video tutorial.
5. if I uncomment ***dump($result);***  , it will insert 1 record normally.

### I am using wampserver on windows, PHP version is 7.3.1. I am a freshman on PHP. So I don't know what is the problem.

rq() is in web.php

```
function rq($key=null, $default=null){
    if(!$key)return Request::all();
    return Request::get($key,$default);
}

    function question_ins(){
        return new App\Question;
    }

    Route::any('api/question/add', function () {

        return(question_ins()->add_question());
    });
```

Comment: Could you provide more context about where this conditionals is being used?

Comment: hi mdexp, I add whole function . please take a look. thanks

Comment: Could you please provide the controller action or route closure/function (if you have one) that calls the `add_question` method. The ternary statement (using `?` and `:`) is the same as the conditional statement (using `if` and `else`) from a programming standpoint, so your code will work exactly the same in both cases. Also where is the `rq()` function defined? The tutorial you're following doesn't seem to guide you into doing things properly, because in general the method `add_question` should not be part of your model class.

Comment: hi Bogdan, you are right, I test again, and find the difference. please check updated question.  Will it be browser-related? But I check it with ie and chrome, both same problem.

Comment: OMG, it acts different on different browser. I check it with Mozilla, it won't happen, why?

Comment: if I add "dump($result);", it can work properly on ie and chrome, but no matter add dump() or not, it can work well on mozilla. Does anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the tutorial you're following.

Comment: sorry it is a china website and it is paid video.  the code is the same, but the teacher use a mac PC.

Comment: Welcome J.S to Stack Overflow! As @Bogdan pointed out, there's a sneaky suspicion that your tutorial isn't steering you down the right path. I recommend reading up on [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) and [RESTful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671118/what-exactly-is-restful-programming) applications.

Comment: As for your question, the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models) on inserting and updating Eloquent models should help you out here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ***create a db table named questions and a model named Question.***

Read about defining Models [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#defining-models)

From your CLI:

`php artisan make:model Question --migration`

**Edit your Question Model:**

```
<?php 

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Question extends Model
{
    // Just tweak this for whatever your Model looks like 
    protected $fillable = [
        'subject',
        'body',
        'author'
    ];

}
```

**Edit your create_questions_table migration:**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateQuestionsTable extends Migration
{

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('body');
            $table->string('subject');
            $table->string('author');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
     }


    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('questions');
    }

}
```

From your CLI, run `php artisan migrate`

> ***add a function to save data into db.***

Check out the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#basic-controllers) on Controllers and what you can do with them.

Again from your CLI:

`php artisan make:controller QuestionController`

**QuestionController:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Question;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class QuestionController extends Controller {

    public function store( Request $request )
    {

        // Create a new instance of your Question Model
        //modify input param .
        $question = App\Question::firstOrNew([
            'body' => $request->body,
            'subject' => $request->subject,
            'author' => $request->author
        ]);

        // Then save it to the database
        $question->save();

        return back()->with('success', 'Question posted');

    }

}
```

**Question.blade.php**

```
<form method="POST" action="/question">
    @csrf 
    <input type="text" name="body" id="body" class="form-control">
    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="form-control">
    <input type="text" name="author" id="author" class="form-control">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Ask Question</button>
</form>

@if( session('success') )
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <h3>Question asked!</h3>
    </div>
@endif
```

**Routes/web.php**

```
Route::post('/question', QuestionController@store)->name('ask-question');
```

Comment: hi , thanks for your help, I follow your instruction. it works well.

Comment: hi,@UkraineInTheMembrane, am I right to change input param of firstOrNew() to as bellow:$question = Question::firstOrNew(
            ['body' => $request->body,
            'subject' => $request->subject,
            'author' => $request->author]
        ); I got db insert error using your code. after changing it. it inserts db well.

Comment: Of course @J.S ! That was my mistake - I'll edit my answer. You can read more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models) about using Eloquent to insert / create records.

Comment: Hey @J.S - if this solved your problem, would you mind accepting the answer? Much appreciated!

Comment: How to handle if not to check the others fields which are not where clause